# How to join lines between line spaces in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, newlines, join

Is there a way to join lines between new lines (return), and keep the new line (return)?  Been doing it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> after selecting the text between the new lines, but not practical with large documents.

Something to transform text from:

```
Mary had a 
little lamb.
His fleece was 
white as snow, yeah.

And everywhere 
the child went.
That little lamb 
was sure to go now.

He followed her 
to school one day.
Which broke the 
teachers cool.
```

to:

```
Mary had a little lamb. His fleece was white as snow, yeah.
    
And everywhere the child went. That little lamb was sure to go now.
    
He followed her to school one day. Which broke the teachers cool.
```

Answer (score 2):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!\r\n)\r\n(?!\r\n)`
- Replace with: nothing (empty string)
- Search mode: Regular Expression

Then replace all

`(?<!\r\n)` and `(?!\r\n)` are regex lookarounds to make sure that you match exactly only 1 new line. If the file is in Unix format then just remove `\r`

---

If you also want to put spaces after punctuation then use this

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `([[:punct:]])(?=\R\S)`
- Replace with: `\1`  (with a space at the end)
- Search mode: Regular Expression
- Replace All, then do the `(?<!\r\n)\r\n(?!\r\n)` replacement above

Comment: It's better to use `\R` that matches any kind of linebreak.

Comment: @Toto it doesn't work inside lookarounds

Comment: Right, my bad. It only works in lookahead.

Comment: This one works, but is joining words from two lines right after the other. Is there a way to join lines keeping the last word separate from the first? Or to keep the space at the end of the line?

Comment: @mr_kultist no, how can it know `.` is the period? It's your job to put a space after that. Regex is just a text searching tool and not a typing syntax tool. You can put a space in multiple replacements but it doesn't work for all cases

Comment: @mr_kultist see my edit

Comment: How can I put a space before after each line, not only the ones with a dot?  

The little lamb was an example, but the documents I'm working on, there are multiple words from two consecutive lines that are joined together after using your replace.  This did not happened with the CTRL-J function of notepad++

Comment: ^^ should say add space after each line ending

Comment: in the example above there are already spaces at the end of lines

Answer (score 0):

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(.+)\R(.+)\R(.+)\R(.+\R?)`
- Replace with: `$1$2$3$4`
- Search mode: Regular Expression
- Click Replace All

**Before**

[image: Input before clicking Replace All]

**After**

[image: Output after clicking Replace All]